# Einstein Email Recommendation with Content Builder

Tags: html, einstein, content-builder

I've created a display within Einstein Email Recommendations (using HTML and placeholders/dynamic variables, like src="%%ContentImageLink%%, for example) where it takes dynamic data and populates a block based on user interaction (with image, text and button).

To create it, I used the same configuration as a template created in Content Builder, i.e. the same style, parameters, etc.

However, when I try to import this logic into a new HTML block within this template that I have in Content Builder (or using the Einstein content in Advanced Content), it goes completely unconfigured (it becomes much smaller than the blocks above).

And when I try to edit the code provided by Email Recommendations, it enlarges the image too much (causing it to lose quality).

Is there a way to make the display created in Email Recommendations follow exactly the same parameters as the Content Block email? Perhaps the problem is with the dynamic/placeholder variables? Because they don't have defined size and quality specifications?

I've attached an example image showing the size and format of the blocks above and the size and format of the blocks imported by Email Recommendations (using the same HTML configuration).[image: Block Example]

And here's the code that I have used:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-bottom: 25px;width:100%;">
 <tbody style="box-shadow: 0px 5px 11px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); border-radius: 11px;">
  <tr>
   <td style="border-radius: 11px 11px 0px 0px; border: 2px solid #AB3097;border-bottom: none;">
    <img alt="%%ContentID%%" src="%%ContentImageLink%%" style="height: 188px; width: 100%; border-radius: 11px 11px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center;"></td></tr><tr>
   <td style="border-radius: 0px 0px 11px 11px; background: white; padding: 20px 30px; display: table-cell;border: 2px solid #AB3097; border-top: none; text-align:center;">
    <div>
     <p style="margin: 0px 0px 7px 0px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 14px;font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;line-height: 24px; text-align:left;color:#AB3097;">%%Time%%</p>
     <p style="margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 22px;font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;line-height: 32px; text-align: left;">%%[if ContentTitleLengthNum &lt; 31 then ]%%%%ContentTitle%%%%[else]%%%%ContentTitleFirst27%%...%%[ endif ]%%</p>      
    <a href="%%ContentLink%%" style="padding: 15px 0px;justify-content: center;align-items: center;align-self: stretch;border-radius: 4px;background: #AB3097;color: white;font-family: Arial;font-size: 12px;font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;line-height: normal;letter-spacing: 0.07px;margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;border-color: transparent;width: 100%;cursor: pointer;text-decoration: none; display:block;">Learn more</a>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```